# Python Threads, why threads in two dimensions aren't work?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this script:

```
import threading
import time
import sys

def threadWait(d1, d2):
    global number
    time.sleep(1) # My actions
    number = number+1 # Count of complete actions +1
    sys.stdout.write("\033[K") # Clean line to the end.
    sys.stdout.write(str(number)+" (Thread "+str(d1)+", "+str(d2)+") done"+"\r") # Write number and carriage return.
    sys.stdout.flush()

number = 0 # Count of complete actions
threadsToJoin = []

dimension1 = [] # Main action task.
for i in range(50): # I have 50 "Main Actions" I need to do in parallel threads.
    d1 = i
    dimension2 = [] # I need to do each "Main Action" in 10 threads.
    for n in range(10):
        d2 = n
        dimension2.append(threading.Thread(target=threadWait, args=(d1,d2)))

    dimension1.append(dimension2)




for item in dimension1:
    for items in dimension2:
        # But I can't do more than 100 Threads at once.
        while True:
            # Analogue of BoundedSemaphore.
            if (int(threading.activeCount()) < 100):
                items.start()
                threadsToJoin.append(items)
                break
            else:
                continue

for this in threadsToJoin:
    this.join()
```

But I'm getting an error about "Thread can't be started twice". But when I'm adding all threads in `dimension2` and running like this:

```
for item in dimension2:
    # But I can't do more than 100 Threads at once.
    while True:
        # Analogue of BoundedSemaphore.
        if (int(threading.activeCount()) < 100):
            item.start()
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Everythin is going good as excpected. What is wrong with the first example and how can I do the whole threading(multithreading) as they do it nowadays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean here:

```
for item in dimension1:
    for items in dimension2:
```

Do you mean:

```
for item in dimension1:
    for items in item:
```

I suppose you don't want to run threads in [dimension2] every cycle

Comment: It is so stupid mistake 0_O Sorry, sometimes I need to take a cat nap to clean my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your nested loop iterates over something else than you think:

```
for item in dimension1:
    for items in dimension2:
        # But I can't do more than 100 Threads at once.
```

Ask yourself a question where is `dimension2` defined?
If you find it hard to figure out, here's the answer:

```
for i in range(50): # I have 50 "Main Actions" I need to do in parallel threads.
    d1 = i
    dimension2 = [] # I need to do each "Main Action" in 10 threads.
```

After program leaves the first nested loops (those where you create "dimensions" in) variable `dimension2` holds the value from last iteration of `for i in range(50)` loop. 
Fixing the problem you have involves doing this:

```
for dimension2 in dimension1:
    for items in dimension2:
        # But I can't do more than 100 Threads at once.
```

The very reason for your problem is trying to reuse variable names in a different context. However the list which you build in `dimension2` has no notion of variable name where it is stored in.

Comment: Thanx! I really did a stupid logic mistake :D Is there a better way of running threads? Maybe more modern ways?